# Can't get pyperclip on Anaconda (Python 3.7)

Tags: anaconda

I've tried

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyperclip
```

and get the following error:

```
Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

---

I've also try to download pyperclip-1.7.0.tar.gz, unzip it (the folder is pyperclip-1.7.0) and copy it to multiple folders (e.g. ...\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts and ...\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib)
but when I try to import it, I get a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'" message

Comment: It worked using pip install pyperclip in the Anaconda prompt (I was using CMD)

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install pyperclip
```

worked from the Anaconda prompt (I was using CMD)